# Retrieving keys from an object by knowing its values

Tags: javascript

hi all...

```
 var fruits = {
        "apple": "fruits/apple.png",
        "banana": "fruits/banana.png",
        "watermelon": "fruits/watermelon.jpg" 
    }
    var fruitsKeys = Object.keys(fruits);
    var fruitsValue = Object.values(fruits);
```

Im looking for a practical way to call back keys from an object through knowing its values .

To explain why I need that, I want to assign each value to a picture and by clicking the picture names Keys will appear.

Appreciate your support

```js
var imgHolder = document.querySelectorAll("#imageholder");
var displayedChallengeName = document.querySelector("#challengeName");
displayedChallengeName.textContent = "Challenge";

var fruits = {
  "apple": "fruits/apple.png",
  "banana": "fruits/banana.png",
  "watermelon": "fruits/watermelon.jpg",
  "grapes": "fruits/grapes.png",
  "orange": "fruits/orange.jpg",
  "mango": "fruits/mango.jpg" 
}
 
var fruitsKeys = Object.keys(fruits);
var fruitsValue = Object.values(fruits);

var displayedFruits = [];
var repeated = 0;
for(var i = 0; i<10; i++){ 
  var z = fruitsValue[justRandomNum()];
  if(displayedFruits.includes(z) ){
   repeated += 1;
  }else{
   displayedFruits.push(z);
  }
 }

for(var i = 0; i<imgHolder.length; i++){
 imgHolder[i].setAttribute("src", displayedFruits[i]);

}

function challengeName(){
 randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * fruitsKeys.length);
 return fruitsKeys[randomNum];

}

function justRandomNum(){
 randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * fruitsValue.length);
 return randomNum;
}
```

```css
body { 
 background-color: #A8F2FE;
 margin: 0;
 }


#h1 {
 background-color: #F9EAA0;
 padding-bottom: 12vh;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 10vh;
 font-family: 'Pangolin', cursive;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 50px;
 color: #223481;
 border: 6px solid #4B9AE8;
}

#h2 {
 font-family: 'Pangolin', cursive;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 50px;
 color: #223481;
}

#challengeName {
 margin: 30px auto;
 font-size: 150%;
}

#holder { 
 height: 200px;
 width: 200px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 10px;
}

.container { 
 margin: 30px auto;
}

.images {
 width: 100%;
 /*padding-bottom: 45%;*/
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 background-color: white;
 /*right: 0;
 bottom: 0;*/
 float: left;
 /*margin: 2.5%;*/
 height: 100%;
 border: 2px solid #25336D;
 /*transition: all 0.3s;*/
 /*top: 50%;
   left: 50%;*/
  /* min-height: 100%;
   min-width: 100%;*/
  /* transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
}

#cont {
 margin: 20px auto;
 /*max-width: 400px;*/
}

#buttonsbar { 
 text-align: center;
 height: 40px;
 }

 #space { 
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5%;
  }
button { 
 text-transform: uppercase;
 height: 100%;
 width: 120px;

 }


 button:hover { 
  color: yellow;
  background-color: gray;
  transition: 0.3s;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Names Game</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="namesgame.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pangolin" rel="stylesheet">
 <style type="text/css">
      body { background: #A8F2FE !important; } /* Adding !important forces the browser to overwrite the default style applied by Bootstrap */
 </style>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
</head>
<body>
 
  <h1 id="h1">Names and Pictures Game
   <br>
   <br>
   <span id="challengeName">MANGO</span>
  </h1> 


 <div id="buttonsbar">
  <button class="rounded">Start</button>
  <span id="space"></span>
  <button class="rounded" >Reset</button>
 </div>
 

 <div class="container">
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
   <div >
    <div id="holder" ><img id="imageholder" class="images" src=""></div>
    <div id="holder" ><img id="imageholder" class="images" src=""></div>
   </div>
   <div >
    <div id="holder" ><img id="imageholder" class="images" src=""></div>
    <div id="holder" ><img id="imageholder" class="images" src=""></div>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
</body>
</html>
© 2018 GitHub, Inc.
```

Comment: Please don't post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time and then your question is meaningless. Please post all relevant code, right here in your question as a "code snippet" (which I have done for you).

Comment: An alternative approach here would be to add a `data-fruit` attribute to each `img` element as you create it and check that rather than `src` when the element is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of values to keys using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), and [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to switch the key and value:

```js
const fruits = {
  "apple": "fruits/apple.png",
  "banana": "fruits/banana.png",
  "watermelon": "fruits/watermelon.jpg"
}

const valuesToKeys = new Map(Object.entries(fruits).map(([k, v]) => [v, k]));

console.log(valuesToKeys.get('fruits/apple.png'));
```

Another option is to use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create an object with switched keys and values:

```js
const fruits = {
  "apple": "fruits/apple.png",
  "banana": "fruits/banana.png",
  "watermelon": "fruits/watermelon.jpg"
};

const fruitsByValues = Object.keys(fruits)
  .reduce((r, k) => {
    r[fruits[k]] = k;
  
    return r;
  }, {});
  
console.log(fruitsByValues['fruits/watermelon.jpg']);
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot ... really appreciated

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the keys using `Object.keys` and then use `Array.find` to find the key that is associated with the value.

```js
const fruits = {
  "apple": "fruits/apple.png",
  "banana": "fruits/banana.png",
  "watermelon": "fruits/watermelon.jpg"
}

function getKeyByValue(obj, value) {
  return Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key] === value)
}

console.log(getKeyByValue(fruits, 'fruits/apple.png'));
```